# Region not rendering on views page but works perfectly on regular pages!

Tags: views, routes, theming, navigation

I have a navigation_bar region set up in my .info file which renders perfectly on regular drupal pages but I have two pages which are made from Views, but nothing renders. I am using the superfish module to display my menu block which is in the navigation_bar region. My search bar is in the header region and it displays fine on all pages. When I tried to move the menu into the header region it still doesn't work ! Anyone have an idea what probably might be?

Thanks,
Rita

Comment: Is it possible you placed a directive in the block's settings that might be keeping it off of the page where it's not showing up?

Comment: Great, I added this as an answer in case someone with the same problem finds this topic.

Answer (score 0):

From the Blocks settings page at admin/structure/block/manage, go to the configuration for the block in question. In the block's "Visibility settings" section, make sure the "Pages" settings are configured in such a way that the block is not hidden from the View page you are having trouble with.